# Опрос COM-порта

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Я пишу прогу, которая должна принимать данные из COM-порта. Я просто взял и в бесконечном цикле while вставил команду чтения данных из порта, но когда я запускаю прогу, она зависает (этого следовало ожидать=)). Как сделать так, чтобы прога не все время считывала данные, а только тогда, когда они появляются на входе COM-порта. Я на C# кодить начал недавно, поэтому, если вам не сложно, покажите пример кода. Спасибо.

Comment: @Tronand: А как вы читаете данные из COM-порта сейчас?
_____
@Tronand: Может быть, [этот пример](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (прокрутите к середине страницы) — то, что вам нужно?

Comment: Так есть же специальный компонент, который генерирует события, когда данные в порт приходят? SerialPort вроде называется.

Comment: Сейчас я читаю данные вот так:
SerialPort SP = new SerialPort("COM4", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
SP.Open();
SP.Read(buffimp, 0, 8);
Но как я уже писал это происходит в бесконечном цикле. А мне нужно чтобы данные считывались только тогда, когда они поступили на вход.

Comment: @Tronand: Так загляните в пример же!

Comment: Да да! Загляни! и не на прямую читай из порта, а подпишись на DataReceived.

если так уж хочется напрямую читать - сделай отдельный трид и его зацикли на чтение. Но это не есть хорошо.